# How can I determine if NSMagnificationGesture is pinching or zooming

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, gesture

I have an `NSMagnificationGesture` in the storyboard, it's linked to an action called `pinchGesture`. Its also linked to an outlet called `pinchZoomOut`

When I pinch on the trackpad this works well, and triggers the `doPinch()` function.
The problem is it also triggers it if you pinch **and** if you zoom.
I want it to trigger just on pinch gesture, not on zoom.

I figure I need to read the contents out the `pinchZoomOut` outlet and then have an `if` statement to determine if its pinching or zooming. The below code is reporting "Cannot convert value of type 'NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer?' to expected argument type 'Double'" if I can get the double from `pinchZoomOut` I might be able to move forward.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction, my current code is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pinchZoomOut: NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer! // the outlet

@IBAction func pinchGesture(_ sender: Any) {

    if pinchZoomOut > 0.3 {
        doPinch() // I want this to trigger on pinch only, not zoom.
    }
}
```

Any assistance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer?' to expected argument type 'Double'

The error is pretty clear. `pinchZoomOut` is a `NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer?`, **not** a number. You probably want to use its [`magnification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmagnificationgesturerecognizer/1510428-magnification) property instead.

```
if pinchZoomOut.magnification > 0.3 {
    doPinch() // I want this to trigger on pinch only, not zoom.
}
```